# Problem running lambda function locally with AWS SAM command on Fedora 32. Docker problem

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, fedora, aws-sam-cli

Did anyone have any luck trying to properly install docker on Fedora 32 and run sam local commands? When I try to execute I get the following error every time:

**ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/....**

The code runs perfectly on a debian based system, so it is not a problem with the code. It is a problem with the Fedora 32 docker installation.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share your docker file or the way how you are use aws sam cli tool.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to fix the permissions for your deployment package.

Run the following command in the CLI to fix the permissions recursively :

```
$ chmod 644 $(find /tmp/package_contents -type f)$ chmod 755 $(find /tmp/package_contents -type d)
```

Once you are done with fixing the permissions, upload the deployment package again and give it a try.